# Display Hint to Spinner after button click?

Tags: android, spinner, reset

I am able to Display Hint to the Spinner through the layout.I want to achieve the spinner field to be clear after the click in Submit button and should display hint. I am using **spinner_district.setSelection(1);** it is displaying  the array of value 1 but  i want to display hint not any value of spinner.

**for clearing field**

```
 registerSchoolName.setText("");
                    registerSchoolAddress.setText("");
                    registerSchoolPhone.setText("");
                    registerSchoolEmail.setText("");
                    registerSchoolWebsite.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee1.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee2.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee3.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee3.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee4.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee5.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee6.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee7.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee8.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee9.setText("");
                    schoolEstDate.setText("");
                    schoolAdmissionStartDate.setText("");
                    schoolAdmissionEndDate.setText("");


                    //  spinner_district.setAdapter(null);
                    spinner_district.setPrompt("District");


                    // spinner_district.setSelection(1);
```

**function**

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.send_school_registration_form:
                if (isConnected()) {
                    String name = registerSchoolName.getText().toString();
                    String address = registerSchoolAddress.getText().toString();
                    String phone = registerSchoolPhone.getText().toString();
                    String email = registerSchoolEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
                    String website = registerSchoolWebsite.getText().toString();
                    String estbdate = schoolEstDate.getText().toString();
                    String admissionOpen = schoolAdmissionStartDate.getText().toString();
                    String admissionEnd = schoolAdmissionEndDate.getText().toString();
                    district = null;


                    if (spinner_district != null && spinner_district.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                        district = (String) spinner_district.getSelectedItem();
                    }

                    country = null;
                    if (spinner_country != null && spinner_country.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                        country = (String) spinner_country.getSelectedItem();
                    }

                    institution = null;
                    if (spinner_institution != null && spinner_institution.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                        institution = (String) spinner_institution.getSelectedItem();
                    }

                    fee = registerSchoolFee.getText().toString();
                    level = null;
                    if (spinner_school_level != null && spinner_school_level.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                        level = (String) spinner_school_level.getSelectedItem();
                    }

                    if (addSchoolProgram1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        fee1 = registerSchoolFee1.getText().toString();
                        level1 = null;
                        if (spinner_school_level1 != null && spinner_school_level1.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                            level1 = (String) spinner_school_level1.getSelectedItem();
                        }


                    }

                    if (addSchoolProgram2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        fee2 = registerSchoolFee2.getText().toString();
                        level2 = null;
                        if (spinner_school_level2 != null && spinner_school_level2.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                            level2 = (String) spinner_school_level2.getSelectedItem();
                        }
                    }

                    if (addSchoolProgram3.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        fee3 = registerSchoolFee3.getText().toString();
                        level3 = null;
                        if (spinner_school_level3 != null && spinner_school_level3.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                            level3 = (String) spinner_school_level3.getSelectedItem();
                        }
                    }

                    if (addSchoolProgram4.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        fee4 = registerSchoolFee4.getText().toString();
                        level4 = null;
                        if (spinner_school_level4 != null && spinner_school_level4.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                            level4 = (String) spinner_school_level4.getSelectedItem();
                        }
                    }

                    if (addSchoolProgram5.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        fee5 = registerSchoolFee5.getText().toString();
                        level5 = null;
                        if (spinner_school_level5 != null && spinner_school_level5.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                            level5 = (String) spinner_school_level5.getSelectedItem();
                        }
                    }

                    if (addSchoolProgram6.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        fee6 = registerSchoolFee6.getText().toString();
                        level6 = null;
                        if (spinner_school_level6 != null && spinner_school_level6.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                            level6 = (String) spinner_school_level6.getSelectedItem();
                        }
                    }

                    if (addSchoolProgram7.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        fee7 = registerSchoolFee7.getText().toString();
                        level7 = null;
                        if (spinner_school_level7 != null && spinner_school_level7.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                            level7 = (String) spinner_school_level7.getSelectedItem();
                        }
                    }

                    if (addSchoolProgram8.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        fee8 = registerSchoolFee8.getText().toString();
                        level8 = null;
                        if (spinner_school_level8 != null && spinner_school_level8.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                            level8 = (String) spinner_school_level8.getSelectedItem();
                        }
                    }

                    if (addSchoolProgram9.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        fee9 = registerSchoolFee9.getText().toString();
                        level9 = null;
                        if (spinner_school_level9 != null && spinner_school_level9.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                            level9 = (String) spinner_school_level9.getSelectedItem();
                        }
                    }

                    if ((name.matches("")) || (address.matches("")) || (phone.matches("")) || (email.matches("")) || (website.matches("")) || (estbdate.matches("")) || (admissionOpen.matches(""))
                            || (admissionEnd.matches("")) || (district.matches("")) || (country.matches("")) || (institution.matches("")) || (fee.matches("")) || (level.matches("")) ||
                            (schoolLogoUpload.getDrawable() == null)
                            ) {

                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill up all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        if ((email.matches(emailPattern)) && ((Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(website)).matches())) {
                            Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) schoolLogoUpload.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                            new UploadImage(image, name, address, phone, email, website, district, country, institution, estbdate, fee, level, fee1, level1, fee2, level2, fee3, level3, fee4, level4, fee5, level5, fee6, level6, fee7, level7,
                                    fee8, level8, fee9, level9, admissionOpen,
                                    admissionEnd).execute();

                        } else
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid website and email address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    registerSchoolName.setText("");
                    registerSchoolAddress.setText("");
                    registerSchoolPhone.setText("");
                    registerSchoolEmail.setText("");
                    registerSchoolWebsite.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee1.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee2.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee3.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee3.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee4.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee5.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee6.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee7.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee8.setText("");
                    registerSchoolFee9.setText("");
                    schoolEstDate.setText("");
                    schoolAdmissionStartDate.setText("");
                    schoolAdmissionEndDate.setText("");


                    //  spinner_district.setAdapter(null);
                    spinner_district.setPrompt("District");


                    // spinner_district.setSelection(1);
                    //spinner_district.setSelection(1);


                    Spinner spinner_country, spinner_institution, spinner_school_level, spinner_school_level1, spinner_school_level2, spinner_school_level3, spinner_school_level4,
                            spinner_school_level5, spinner_school_level6, spinner_school_level7, spinner_school_level8, spinner_school_level9;


                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.cancel_school_registration_form:
                this.finish();
                break;
            case R.id.register_school_logo:
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                break;
            case R.id.register_school_estdate:
                datePickerDialogSchool.show();
                break;
            case R.id.school_admission_startDate:
                schoolAdmissionStartDatePicker.show();
                break;
            case R.id.school_admission_end_date:
                schoolAdmissionEndDatePicker.show();
                break;
            case R.id.add_more_school_programs:
                if (addMoreSchoolProgram.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    if (addSchoolProgram9.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        if (addSchoolProgram8.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                            if (addSchoolProgram7.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                                if (addSchoolProgram6.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                                    if (addSchoolProgram5.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                                        if (addSchoolProgram4.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                                            if (addSchoolProgram3.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                                                if (addSchoolProgram2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                                                    if (addSchoolProgram1.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                                                        addSchoolProgram1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    } else
                                                        addSchoolProgram2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                } else
                                                    addSchoolProgram3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            } else
                                                addSchoolProgram4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        } else
                                            addSchoolProgram5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    } else
                                        addSchoolProgram6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                } else
                                    addSchoolProgram7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            } else
                                addSchoolProgram8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else
                            addSchoolProgram9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else
                        addMoreSchoolProgram.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.register_school_email:
        }
    }
```

> How can resetting to spinner be done with providing hint not the
>   spinner values??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following **code** to solve the issue

```
admissionEnd).execute();
                        registerSchoolName.setText("");
                        registerSchoolAddress.setText("");
                        registerSchoolPhone.setText("");
                        registerSchoolEmail.setText("");
                        registerSchoolWebsite.setText("");
                        registerSchoolFee.setText("");
                        registerSchoolFee1.setText("");
                        registerSchoolFee2.setText("");
                        registerSchoolFee3.setText("");
                        registerSchoolFee3.setText("");
                        registerSchoolFee4.setText("");
                        registerSchoolFee5.setText("");
                        registerSchoolFee6.setText("");
                        registerSchoolFee7.setText("");
                        registerSchoolFee8.setText("");
                        registerSchoolFee9.setText("");
                        schoolEstDate.setText("");
                        schoolAdmissionStartDate.setText("");
                        schoolAdmissionEndDate.setText("");


                        //  spinner_district.setAdapter(null);
                        spinner_district.setPrompt("District");
                        spinner_district.setSelection(0);
```

> use setPrompt and setSelection

Comment: Just a minute.I will get on this.